# Why is it 'Alexei' but 'Sergey'?

Tags: translation, names, transliteration

Why is it 'Alexei' but 'Sergey' (at least, according to Wikipedia)? Shouldn't there be uniform rules on how to transliterate Russian names? How do I render the endings '-ей'?

Comment: According to wikipedia, both Sergei and Sergey are acceptable transliterations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergius_(name)#List_of_people_with_given_name_Sergei_or_Sergey

Comment: The czar decided it. The tsar disagreed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about transliteration of Russian rather than about English.

Comment: Transliteration is rarely exact, and depends on conventions used. For example, the guttural "ch", as in Arabic ح or Hebrew ח may be transliterated as "ch", "h', "χ", "ḥ", "ħ", etc. Russian is easy compared to Khoisan, for example.

Answer (score 2):

There *are* standard rules. When I worked as a library cataloguer, I sometimes had to use them to transliterate the titles etc. of Russian books such as art exhibition catalogues. However, other informal transliterations have passed into the English language. Don't forget that Wikipedia is compiled by many different people.

A century ago, Chekhov was always called Tchekhov in English books. We still use the spelling *Tchaikovsky* (adapted from the German transliteration *Tschaikowsky*). Some decades ago, the library world started using *Chaikovski'i* in accordance with the rules, but after a time it was dropped because the public are so familiar with the spelling beginning with 'T' that it caused confusion.

Comment: What about my examples?

Comment: It was probably [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALA-LC_romanization_for_Russian) that I used. I suppose it would be Aleksei and Sergei (but of course most English speakers would write Alexander and Alexei because we're used to using the letter 'x' in such names).

Comment: The question was "why", though

Comment: Most English speakers are not familiar with the official transliteration tables. As I explained two years ago, some nonstandard transliterations have passed into common use and it would be confusing to change them. You could just as well call yourself Sergei, but it might confuse your English-speaking friends if you suddenly changed it.